# how use column from one subquery to anoter subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two subquery .i want put p.price from first subquery into secound subquery(place XXX) . but get error => ORA-00904: "P"."PRICE": invalid identifier

```
select 
    p.product_id,
    p.price, 
    l.delegation, 
    l.state 
from users
inner join (
    select 
        start_date,
        price,
        product_id, 
        row_number() over (partition by serial order by start_date desc ) as rn
    from prices 
) p on users.serial = p.serial 
inner join (
    select 
        sso_id , 
        delegation,
        state,
        updated_at, 
        row_number() over (partition by state order by updated_at asc) as tl  
    from payments
    where state = 'green' or (state = 'yellow' and delegation > XXX)
) l on users.sso_id= l.sso_id
where  
    p.rn = 1 
    and l.tl = 1
```

Comment: It would helo if you could please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text.

Comment: it gives different error. [Error] Execution (14: 29): ORA-00904: "P"."SERIAL": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it in the main `WHERE` clause

```
select 
    p.product_id,
    p.price, 
    l.delegation, 
    l.state 
from users
inner join (
    select 
        start_date,
        price,
        product_id, 
        row_number() over (partition by serial order by start_date desc ) as rn
    from prices 
) p on users.serial = p.serial 
inner join (
    select 
        sso_id , 
        delegation,
        state,
        updated_at, 
        row_number() over (partition by state order by updated_at asc) as tl  
    from payments
    where state = 'green' or state = 'yellow'
) l on users.sso_id= l.sso_id
where  
    p.rn = 1 
    and l.tl = 1 
    -- add following condition
and l.delegation > p.price
```

Comment: Solved! No need to  CASE , just i use 'l.delegation<p.price'  in main WHERE clause without CASE statement.@Tejash

Comment: This will generate the `ROW_NUMBER` for the second sub-query first and then try to filter by price afterwards; the OP wants to filter by price first and then generate the `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @behzadomidi [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9ae68529eab32ea03a41324f5e1b8981) This does not get a row with `yellow` state if the row with the earliest `updated_at` has a `delegation <= price` even if there exists a row that has `state = 'yellow'` and `delegation > price` with a later `updated_at` value.

Answer (score 1):

Join on the `PAYMENTS` table and filter the rows to exclude the invalid `state`/`delegation` rows and then generate the `ROW_NUMBER` and filter to find the first row per partition:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users ( serial, sso_id ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE prices ( serial, start_date, price, product_id ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-01', 20, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-02-01', 30, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-03-01', 25, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-01-01', 20, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-02-01', 25, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-03-01', 30, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2019-01-01', 40, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE payments ( sso_id, delegation, state, updated_at ) AS
SELECT 1, 20, 'green',  DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 30, 'green',  DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 27, 'green',  DATE '2019-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 22, 'green',  DATE '2019-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 26, 'yellow', DATE '2019-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 31, 'yellow', DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 31, 'green',  DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 30, 'green',  DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 30, 'yellow', DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 50, 'yellow', DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT product_id,
       price, 
       delegation, 
       state
FROM   (
  select p.product_id,
         p.price, 
         l.delegation, 
         l.state,
         row_number() over ( partition by l.sso_id, l.state order by l.updated_at asc) as tl  
  from   users
         inner join (
           select serial,
                  start_date,
                  price,
                  product_id, 
                  row_number() over (partition by serial order by start_date desc ) as rn
           from   prices 
         ) p
         on ( users.serial = p.serial AND p.rn = 1 )
         inner join payments l
         on ( users.sso_id = l.sso_id AND ( l.state = 'green' or (l.state = 'yellow' and l.delegation > p.price ) ) )
)
where  tl = 1
```

**Output**:

> ```
> PRODUCT_ID | PRICE | DELEGATION | STATE 
> ---------: | ----: | ---------: | :-----
>          3 |    25 |         20 | green 
>          3 |    25 |         26 | yellow
>          3 |    30 |         31 | green 
>          3 |    30 |         31 | yellow
>          3 |    40 |         30 | green 
>          3 |    40 |         50 | yellow
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0525069bfdb52aef96e1235e175ba9e1)*

Answer (score 0):

We need to rejoin your `users` and `price` table to your `payment` to get matching `p.price`

```
SELECT p.product_id,
    p.price,
    l.delegation,
    l.state
FROM users
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT start_date,
        price,
        product_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serial ORDER BY start_date DESC) AS rn
    FROM prices) p ON users.serial = p.serial
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT y.sso_id,
        y.delegation,
        y.state,
        y.updated_at,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY y.state ORDER BY y.updated_at ASC) AS tl
    FROM payments y
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.sso_id = y.sso_id
    INNER JOIN prices p ON p.serial = y.serial
    WHERE tl.state = 'green' OR (tl.state = 'yellow' AND tl.delegation > p.price)) l ON users.sso_id = l.sso_id
WHERE  
      AND p.rn = 1 AND l.tl = 1
```

Comment: This will generate the `ROW_NUMBER` for the second sub-query first and then try to filter by state & price afterwards; the OP wants to filter by state & price first and then generate the `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: There's a couple of issues as the first sub-query is missing the `serial` value that is filtered on and its not clear from the OP's query that the `payments` table has a `serial` column to join on however you can use `p.serial = u.serial` in the second sub-query. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6db31218a01d660b4b84d08362948a12) fixes those and appears to work on some test data.